# NotifcationHub Messaging Not Working in my Xamarin iOS App

Tags: azure, push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

Everything looks properly configured. I've gone over it many times. Here's what I got:

Service Bus Explorer returns this when I connect:

```
    <23:36:44> The application is now connected to the 

sb://localesnotify.servicebus.windows.net/ service bus namespace.
<23:36:44> MessagingFactory successfully created
<23:37:24> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. TrackingId:20b6388b-2599-428a-a7b8-2c81eba6b309,TimeStamp:3/4/2017 4:37:24 AM
<23:37:24> InnerException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error
```

In all cases, when I test on my device, RegisteredForRemoteNotifications return successfully.

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        Hub = new SBNotificationHub(Constants.ConnectionString, Constants.NotificationHubPath);

        Hub.UnregisterAllAsync(deviceToken, (error) => {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error calling Unregister: {0}", error.ToString());
                return;
            }

            NSSet tags = null; // create tags if you want
            Hub.RegisterNativeAsync(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) => {
                if (errorCallback != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("RegisterNativeAsync error: " + errorCallback.ToString());
            });
        });

        var alert = new UIAlertView("Remote Notifications", "Registered!", null, "OK", null);

        alert.Show();
    }
```

My certificates and provisioning profiles seem properly configured on both Azure & Xamarin.

I've tried different connection strings and notification hub urls. Not sure exaclty which ones to use. But I tried all I think.

```
// Azure app-specific connection string and hub path
    public const string ConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://localesnotify.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=1QMNeVitGRUxoZvkgnx8klpJGsJ5LfX/057jL+CD2VE=";
    public const string NotificationHubPath = "sb://localesnotify.servicebus.windows.net";
```

When I test send from Azure, it says completed successfully but I never get the message.

My ReceivedRemoteNotification does not fire off. So I guess my client is not properly connected. Also in Classic portal it says No registrations were found for the selected platform.

```
        public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        ProcessNotification(userInfo, false);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Change the `NoficationHubPath` with just the name of the hub as you name it in Azure.

Comment: I have some choices. This is from the classic portal: https://localesnotify.servicebus.windows.net/localesnotify. This is from the new portal: 
Service Endpoint
https://LocalesNotify.servicebus.windows.net:443/. This is the App Service http://locales.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: It's not an url is just a name. In azure this will be the name of the object. The icon is usually of orange color.

Comment: ObjecInAzure:https://www.dropbox.com/s/1oojidpi3ejzoaj/azure-hub.png?dl=0

NameFromProperties: https://www.dropbox.com/s/22ygq2py1u5bg0s/azure-hub-name.png?dl=0

Sorry I am using external links but the comments do not support images.

Comment: Then it's this.. 
LocalesNotify - trying it out now..

Comment: Use that one as the NotificationHubPath, everything in lower case.

Comment: Just the name crashes the App. trying in lowercase.

Comment: U R AWESOME!! IT WORKS!!! after weeks of messing with it, that's all it was.. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Great! You're welcome!

Comment: So happy right  now! Thanks again!

Comment: Added an answer so it doesn't "die" in the comments. It could help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `NotificationHubPath` to the name of the Hub in Azure.

To find it log into Azure and click on the NotificationHub object:

[image: Azure notification hub]

Then select the properties option and the copy the **Name**.

[image: Notification Hub properties]

This is the value you will use as the notificationHubPath in the SBNotificationHub constructor.

```
var hub = new SBNotificationHub ("azureKey", "yournotificationhub");
```

**Note:** Type it all lower case.